# Android openCV can`t IDFT back to orginal image

Tags: android, opencv, inverse, dft

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91yTc.jpg)Hello, i try to transform image from time domain to frequency domain by using opencv DFT() function, it works, but i can`t transform it back by using IDFT() function。
In my getIDFT() function , i get phase from dft complex and use polarToCart to get Re and Im Data, but something wrong with my image , can somebody help me , thanks.

Github : https://github.com/pighaddt/opencv_demo/tree/master/app/src

```
private Mat getIDFT(Mat DFTimage){

    DFTimage.convertTo(DFTimage, CvType.CV_64FC1);
    DFTimage = DFTShift(DFTimage);


    Mat Re = new Mat(DFTimage.size(), CvType.CV_64FC1); // expand input image to optimal size
    Mat Im = new Mat(DFTimage.size(), CvType.CV_64FC1); // expand input image to optimal size
    Mat ph = new Mat(DFTimage.size(), CvType.CV_64FC1);
    Core.phase(planes.get(0), planes.get(1), ph, false);

    Core.polarToCart(DFTData, ph, Re, Im, false);
    Mat complexI = Mat.zeros(Re.rows(), Re.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);
    Mat complexI3 = Mat.zeros(Re.rows(), Re.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC2);
    List<Mat> planesIDFT = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    planesIDFT.add(Re);
    planesIDFT.add(Im);


    Core.merge(planesIDFT, complexI); // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros

    Mat invDFTcvt = new Mat(Re.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Core.idft(complexI, complexI3, Core.DFT_INVERSE | Core.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT | Core.DFT_SCALE, 0);
    Core.split(complexI3, planesIDFT); // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I)), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))

    Core.normalize(planesIDFT.get(0), invDFTcvt, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX);
    invDFTcvt.convertTo(invDFTcvt, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    isDFT = false;
    return invDFTcvt;
}
```

Comment: *why* do you use polarToCart?

Comment: i want get Re and Im data from dft complex